# Z-Wave Hub that works with Google Home in Australia

Tags: smart-home, google-home, google-assistant, zwave

Does anyone know of any hubs that support Australian Z-Wave and also can be controlled by the Google Assistant. Things such as SmartThings and Wink hub are not available in Australia due to not being able to run on certain frequencies. Are there any alternatives. There is the Leviton hub, but this doesn’t support Google assistant. Importing a hub would also not be an option. This is because it is illegal and would be next to impossible to find z-wave devices that support the US frequency and are also 240v. What options do I have? I can’t find any but maybe I’m not looking hard enough.

Comment: Do you have any specific devices that you want to connect to the hub? The issue with the other hubs are that they use the US Z-Wave frequencies, which are illegal to use in Australia as they interfere with mobile frequencies. If you're not looking to use Z-Wave, then that might narrow down your search.